# Unable to open a dataset in h5py

Tags: hdf5, h5py, hdf

When I try to import a folder with h5py, I am able to open. However, when I try to access its datasets, it says there is an error. Is there a reason why?

The code below is used to import the folder:

```
hf = h5py.File('filename', 'r')
```

However, when I use the code below, there is an error:

```
x = np.array(hf["dataset"])
```

Comment: You must be doing something wrong! (if you want more help you need to give more information, like the text of the error).  Do you know, for sure, that there's a `dataset` called `dataset`?  Or is that just a guess or random choice?  How much of the `h5py` "getting started" documentation have you read (and understood)?

Comment: The error says "Unable to open object (object 'signal' doesn't exist)". I am sure that the dataset is there. I read most of the h5py doucmentation, and the code above works for other data.

Comment: Why didn't you include that information initially, rather than leaving me guessing as to how much you knew or had already done!  With the little you added I'd suggest first `ds = hf["dataset"]` to verify that you can access the dataset.  Then start displaying some properties - shape, dtype, etc..  And as per the documentation, `x = ds[:]` is the preferred syntax for loading.  But I suspect there's something unusual about this dataset that prevents loading.  If you don't know anything about it, you may have to use a `dump` script to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a small syntax error. Try this (w/out np.array):

```
x = hf['/dataset']
```

I don't think you need the leading '/' to define root level, but it's good practice to include (IMHO).

If that doesn't work, it's time to double check your HDF5 contents. As hpaulj asked, are you sure `dataset` is at the root level? Maybe there's an intermediate group? If so, you need to define the full path to the object:

```
dset_table = hf['/topgroup/dataset']
```

I suggest you use **HDFView** to examine your file, or run the **h5dump** utility. Both are available at the HDF Group Download site. That eliminates coding questions. You can also check group names with the following:

```
list(hf.keys())
```

You should get something like this (if dataset really is at the root level):

```
['dataset']
```

Finally, you can use`.get()` to get the class of the object.

```
get(name, default=None, getclass=False, getlink=False)
```

Set `getclass=True` to get the Object class: `Group` or `Dataset`.